# Center Userform on Multiple Monitors

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I searched for this online for a while, and I did find a few solutions, but none of them appear to help me.

I have a Userform in Excel 2010, which I would like to center on the Excel window. I have dual monitors, and it always seems to center itself between the two monitors. I know there are properties you can edit, such as StartUpPosition and such, to control where it goes, but it seems changing these parameters does nothing. This is the code I found online, which many users attested to working for them. My form is named "HighlightForm"

```
Private Sub HighlightForm_Activate()

    With HighlightForm
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
        .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
        .Show
    End With

End Sub
```

This, however, does not change where my form is placed at all. It remains in the center. I even tried changing all these parameters to zero, to no avail. I'm placing this code in the UserForm code itself, which I understand to be the correct placement. I've also tried HighlightForm_Initialize(), and it still won't respond to any changes.

Is there something blatantly obvious I'm missing? I don't imagine this to be a very difficult question, but I'm really stumped. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Remove `.show`. Form activating will take caring of showing it.

Answer (score 3):

I found this code working perfectly for me

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    'Position top/left of Excel App
    Me.Top = Application.Top
    Me.Left = Application.Left

    'Approx over top/left cell (depends on toolbars visible)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (Application.UsableHeight / 2)
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (Application.UsableWidth / 2)
End Sub
```

To note that you can adjust the "/2" to center a bit more as it might give a different feeling with smaller monitors (it adjust the top left of the Userform to the center of your screen). My Code has 2.3

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but figured I'd point out the error for anyone else who happens across it.

Your sub is called "Private Sub HighlightForm_Activate()"

It must be called "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()"

This is regardless of the name of the userform itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found that changing the `.StartUpPosition = 3` (Windows Default) and with your code to alter top left point, it centers on the Excel window. Unless your Excel is stretched over 2 screens or userform width/height larger than screens, the userform shouldn't be between the monitors.